# How can make like 'Discord' testing voice bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I have a request item make a voice bar.

I try use Css background image cover on the blue rect.

it's result like this.
[image]

The problem the voice bar background color different body background color.

I find just 'Discord' setting page voice bar.

[image]

but I have no idea about how can i do.

Comment: Do you want to control the level of blue lines with CSS?

Comment: I want some an example of plugin. I can't make a oval on cover blue lines.